# Configurable HTML information extraction

Tags: java, web-crawler, information-retrieval, information-extraction

**Scenario:**

I'm doing some HTML information extraction using a crawler. Right now, most the rules for extraction are hardcoded (not the tags or things like that, but loops, nested elements, etc.)

For instance, one common task is as follows:

1. Obtain table with ID X. If it doesn't exists there may be additional mechanisms so find the info which are triggered
2. Find a row which contains some info. Usually the match is a regexp against an specific column.
3. Retrieve the data in a different column (usually marked in the td, or previously detected in the header)

The way I'm currently doing so is:

1. Query to get the body of first table with id X (X is in config file). Some websites of my list are buggy and duplicate that id on elements different than table -.-
2. Iterate over interesting cells, executing regexp on cell.text() (regexp is in config file)
3. Get the parent row of the matching cells, and obtain the cell I need from the row (identifier of the row is in config file)

Having all this hardcoded for the most part (except column names, table ids, etc) gives me the benefit or being easy to implement and more efficiency than a generic parser, however, it is less configurable, and some changes in the target websites force me to deal with code, which makes it harder to delegate the task.

**Question**

Is there any **language** (preferably with a java implementation available) which allows to consistently define rules for extractions like those? I'm using css-style selectors for some tasks, but others are not so simple, so my best guess is that there must be something extending that that a non-programmer maintainer to add/modify rules on demand.

I would accept a Nutch-based answer, if there's one, as we're studying migrating our crawlers to nutch, although, I'd prefer a generic java solution.

I was thinking about writing a Parser generator and create my own set of rules to allow users/maintainers to generate parsers, but it really feels like reinventing the wheel for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something somewhat similar - not exactly what you're searching for, but maybe you can get some ideas.

First the crawling part:
I'm using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) on Python 3.7.
For my project, that brought the advantage, that it's very flexible and an easy crawling framework to build upon. Things like delays between requests, HTTP header language etc. can mostly be configured.

For the information extraction part and rules:
In my last generation of crawler (I'm now working on the 3rd gen, the 2nd one is still running but not as scalable) I've used JSON files to enter the XPath / CSS rules for every page. So on starting my crawler, I've loaded the JSON file for one specific page that is currently being crawled and a generic crawler, knew what to extract based on the loaded JSON file.

This approach isn't easily scalable since one config file per domain has to be created.
Currently, I'm still using Scrapy, with a starting list of 700 Domains to crawl and the crawler is now only responsible for downloading the whole website as HTML files.
These are being stored in tar archives by a shell script.
Afterward, a Python script is going through all members of the shell script and analyzing the content for the information I'm looking to extract.

Here, as you said, it's a bit like re-inventing the wheel or writing a wrapper around an existing library.

In Python, one can use [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) for removing all tags like script and style etc.
Then you can extract for instance all text.
Or you'd focus first on tables only, extract all tables into dicts and can then analyze with regex or similar.
There are libraries like [DragNet](https://github.com/dragnet-org/dragnet) for boilerplate removal.
And there are some specific approaches on [how to extract table structured information](https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-html-tables-with-python-c9baba21059).

Comment: Thats so basic. I wrote a new system in java to configure a totally customizable crawling in nay website, JSON, xml, html, binary (with tika). It's some short of simplification of java languaje itself.

I did it for my enterprise, so i'm not allowed to share. I needed something really complet and generic (even withthe ability to configure a dynamic try/catch, list iteration, etc)